# Re-submission, formatted version of earlier question - Non detection of 'click action' on button returned in ajax response text

Tags: jquery

Situation - just upgrading from pure javascript to jquery - prompted by browser inconsistencies.

On load, an ajax request displays a page in a div with an OK button at the bottom: `<input name="srd_button_ok" type="button" value="OK" />`.

Clicking the OK button IS NOT detected by:

```
$('[name*="srd_button_ok"]').click(function() {
    alert("srd_button_ok clicked"); });
```

However, with another 'test button' (placed in a separate div on same page, permanently displayed) `<input name="test_div" type="button" value="Test Div" />`

Clicking Test Div IS detected by:

```
$('[name*="test_div"]').click(function() {
    alert("test_dv clicked");});
```

Both of the above within

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { ....});
```

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Ivan Rutter

Comment: Would you mind posting the entire block of code for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery live

```
$('[name*="srd_button_ok"]').live(function(){
    alert("srd_button_ok clicked");});
```

Answer (score 0):

use delegate

```
$('body').delegate('[name*="srd_button_ok"]', 'click', function(){
    alert("srd_button_ok clicked");
});
```